# on click is behaving somewhat like a for each... Hard to explain

Tags: jquery

Here's the basic scenario. I have a set of list elements.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="c-id" style="display: none;">1</span>
    <a class="remove_comment">Remove</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="c-id" style="display: none;">2</span>
    <a class="remove_comment">Remove</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="c-id" style="display: none;">3</span>
    <a class="remove_comment">Remove</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The c-id stands for commentID and each has it's own unique identifier. I've created an on click event as follows:

```
$('.remove_comment').on('click', function() {
    var commentBlock = $(this).parent('li');
    var commentID = parseInt(commentBlock.find('.c-id').text());
    console.log(commentID);
});
```

As you can see I'm using console to make sure it's grabbing the appropriate ID, which it does. However, it does a console log 3 times. So for this example if I click on the third remove link it will log in the console the #3, 3 times. If I had 10 list elements and clicked remove on the 3rd one, it would log the number 3, 10 times. So it's directly related to how many li elements are on the page.

Why is it doing this? Basically I expected it to log a single time, and a single value.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Maybe you are binding the event handler in a loop? I cannot reproduce the problem with the code you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/qXsRp/.

Comment: I found out how to fix the problem, but I wish I understood why the problem exists to begin with. I have a page that uses ajax to load a list of services, and from within that ajax load, another ajax to load comments for each service. The script I had was originally attached to the last insert. If I move the on click script up a couple levels to the parent page and use LIVE, the problem disappears. Not sure why though.

Comment: Well, if you bind the event handler inside the Ajax success callback and you make an Ajax call for every comment (or so), so will bind the handler to every *existing* `.remove_comment` element, not only the newly created ones.

Comment: I think @FelixKling hit the nail on the head: since you were adding the event listeners on every Ajax load, you were doing this multiple times. Your solution with `.live()` is indeed the right way to fix it, because now you're setting up a single event listener. However, `.live()` is deprecated, and for good reason. You should use the event delegation option in `.on()` instead. Simply change `$('.remove_comment').on( 'click', function() {...} );` to `$('#yourcontainerelement').on( 'click', '.remove_comment', function() {...});`.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thank you Michael. This leads me to another problem. Starting to head a bit off topic, but current jQuery I'm using is 1.7.2 and there are some touchy scripts within the site, which is why I haven't upgraded yet. I thought 1.7.2 already deprecated the live function, but it doesn't seem to work for dynamically loaded content via ajax. Not sure why.

Comment: `.live()` is available in 1.7.2; [it was removed in 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/). But `.on()` has been [available since 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/on/), so that's the one you should use. `.on()` does let you easily handle events in dynamically loaded content. (So does `.live()`, but it was a bad API from the beginning and shouldn't be used.) What problem did you run into with dynamically loaded content? You need to use `.on()` on the container element - the element the ajax content is loaded into, e.g. `'#yourcontainerelement'` in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably adding the event for every item on your page. But the event code as you wrote it applies to all items, meaning that each item gets N times the same event, where N is the number of items you added.

Comment: Please see my comment posted on my original question. I fixed the issue but wish I could understand why/how it was happening.

Comment: Since I don't have your code and I don't know what it was and what you have fixed, that is pretty hard to answer. But in general, when using Ajax, you can use `on` to set a persistent event handler that automatically works for new content as well.

Comment: For instance: If you use `$('.foo').on('click', '.bar', eventHandler)`, the event will be attached to elements that match '.foo' and will remain as long as those elements remain intact. The event fill *fire* when any element that matches '.bar' within those '.foo' elements is clicked. If you add new '.bar' elements to a '.foo', they automatically respond to the click handler as well, so there is no need to re-assign the event to the new content.